# Using scatter plot to show rectangle with specified direction

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to show a rectangle which its center is at position (x,y) and its long axis at an angle phi to the x-axis. How can I do that?

I can show a circle point in position (x,y) by

```
scatter(x,y)
```

But I have no idea about the rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`fill`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html) to draw 2D polygons from their `x` and `y` coordinates.

```
c = [0, 0];     % Position of centre
h = 5; w = 8;   % height and width of rectangle
a = deg2rad(30); % angle of rotation in radians (using deg2rad so can be set in degrees)
% Get corners of rectangle
corners = [c(1) + w/2, c(2) + h/2; c(1) + w/2, c(2) - h/2; c(1) - w/2, c(2) - h/2; c(1) - w/2, c(2) + h/2];
% rotate corner points
corners = [(corners(:,1)-c(1))*cos(a) - (corners(:,2)-c(2))*sin(a) + c(1), (corners(:,1)-c(1))*sin(a) + (corners(:,2)-c(2))*cos(a) + c(2)];
% Use 'fill' or 'patch' to plot
fill(corners(:,1), corners(:,2), 'r')
```

---

This could be packaged into a function if you wanted to reuse it

```
function [corners(:,1), corners(:,2)] = getRectangle(c, h, w, a)
% This function returns the corner points for a rectangle, specified
% by its centre point c = [x,y], height h, width w and angle in degrees from horizontal a
    a = deg2rad(a);
    corners = [c(1) + w/2, c(2) + h/2; c(1) + w/2, c(2) - h/2; c(1) - w/2, c(2) - h/2; c(1) - w/2, c(2) + h/2];
    corners = [(corners(:,1)-c(1))*cos(a) - (corners(:,2)-c(2))*sin(a) + c(1), (corners(:,1)-c(1))*sin(a) + (corners(:,2)-c(2))*cos(a) + c(2)];
end
```

Use:

```
[rectX, rectY] = getRectangle([0,0], 5, 8, 30);
fill(rectX, rectY, 'r');
```

Comment: I want to use scatter to how lots of data, not plot!

Comment: You just want rectangular points instead of circles when using the scatter function? What has that got to do with the angle of the rectangle to the x-axis? You can scatter with squares by simply putting `scatter(x,y,'d')` or `scatter(x,y,'s')`

Comment: You just want rectangular points instead of circles when using the scatter function? Yes exactly.  What has that got to do with the angle of the rectangle to the x-axis? it's the question I asked.

Comment: So have you tried `scatter(x,y,'s')`? Is that closer to what you want than my answer above?

Comment: No it is not close to what I want

Comment: Please draw a basic example of what you want (for example in paint) and add the image to your question, or try and describe in detail how you want the final figure to look.

Comment: Is there a way to indicate perimeter of the rectangle in a different color?

Comment: You can change almost everything about how it appears, see the [`patch` properties](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch-properties.html), in particular `fill(rectX, rectY, 'r', 'edgecolor', [0.4, 0.8, 0.4])` where the last vector argument is an RGB triplet. Note also that `patch` can be used instead of `fill` to draw multiple shapes

Comment: Thank you. I have asked another question which I think you could solve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44245196/ploting-vector-field-in-certain-interval-in-matlab