# Plot vector field within given region (between two circles) in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to plot below vector field in Matlab:

```
 u = cos(x-x_0).*y-y_0;
 v = sin(x+x_0).*y+y_0;
```

I can do it easily in a grid, for example from -2 to 2 in x and y direction:

```
x_0=2; y_0=1;
[x,y] = meshgrid(-2:0.2:2, -2:0.2:2);
figure
quiver(x,y,u,v)
```

But I want to plot the vector field in a certain region which isn't square like above. The region I want to plot the vector field is the region between two circles, both centered at (x_0,y_0) with radii equal to `r_1=5` and `r_2=10`

How can I do that?

Comment: Please post a complete example (define `x` etc)

Comment: (x ,y) are indicate position in 2d. u and v are vector field in x and y direction @LuisMendo

Comment: Do you want polar plot?

Comment: What is it? I want to plot vector field [u,v] in the region I introduced @OmG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your radii, centre of circle and `x`,`y` variables like so

```
r1 = 5; r2 = 10;  % Radii of your circles
x_0 = 0; y_0 = 1; % Centre of circles
[x,y] = meshgrid(x_0-r2:0.2:x_0+r2,y_0-r2:0.2:y_0+r2); % meshgrid of points
```

Then get which points are within the [annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)) described by the two circles, do this by using the circle equations which define the region:

```
idx = ((x-x_0).^2 + (y-y_0).^2 > r1^2 & (x-x_0).^2 + (y-y_0).^2 < r2^2);
```

Define your vector field

```
u = cos(x-x_0).*y-y_0;
v = sin(x+x_0).*y+y_0;
```

Then plot the vector field of these points using `quiver` like you did:

```
quiver(x(idx),y(idx),u(idx),v(idx));
```

Output:

[image]

---

**Edit:**

If your vector field is complicated, you would save a lot of computation time by first removing elements from `x` and `y` which you are not interested in. After calculating `idx`, do:

```
x = x(idx);
y = y(idx);
```

Then calculate `u` and `v` and you can plot by simply calling `quiver(x,y,u,v)`.

Comment: @OliverRange please see my edit for one additional note on efficiency